# Response with express and nodejs application

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express server and a login page developed in HTML(with jquery). after login button is hit, jQuery fires a HTTP get request to express server and after user gets verified, user should be redirected to landing page with some data like name, gender, age etc(that is fetched from mongoDB on server itself). When I do `res.sendFile` or `res.redirect`, The parameters (name, age, gender) could not be sent on the view which is required there in response.

**Jquery:**

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  user = $("#email").val();
  pass = $("#password").val();
  $.post("https://localhost:443/login", {
    user: user,
    password: pass
  }, function(response) {
    if (response) {
      alert("login success" + response.userName);
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="grad">
  <h1 style="margin-top: -10px;    text-shadow: 1px 1px whitesmoke;">Login</h1>
  <h3 style="padding-bottom: 30px;font-size: 22px ">Please enter email ID and password.</h3>
  <div class="group">

    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Email ID</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="button buttonRed" value="Login" onclick="validateUser()" />
    <input type="reset" class="button buttonRed" value="Reset" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**Express:**

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    // some logic to validate user and fetch details, which will be used on view.
    res.sendFile('landing**strong text**page.html', { root: "public" } );
})
```

Comment: your missing some code

Answer (score 0):

The post route should save the user in session before returning the response to jQuery code. Essentially the response from post route should be only success or response.

There should also be a get route to redirect the user to home page (or the page where u want the user after login).
This get route will first check if there is a user in session then redirect accordingly.

Use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) to save the session in app.

Answer (score 0):

- Simple solution for starter. This is NOT a practical solution in production site, just for starter who wants to learn the basic.

**Jquery**

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  user = $("#email").val();
  pass = $("#password").val();
  $.post("https://localhost:443/login", {
    user: user,
    password: pass
  }, function(response) {
    $('body').append(response); //append html to body returned from /login
  });
});
```

**Express Server:**

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    // some logic to validate user and fetch details, which will be used on view.
    var userInfo = validateAndFetchDetailFunc();
    res.send('Username: ' + userInfo.name + '<br>Gender: ' + userInfo.gender);
})
```

---

- The real solution should be using session to management the login session for user.

  1. User login with username/password
  2. Create a session at the server side, send back a session key or access token to the client.
  3. When the client request user information, use the session key or access token to retrieve the user info
  4. Render the html page with the user info from the saved session

For express server, you can start to learn session with [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session).